# Nested sequence evaluation seems to fail

Tags: list-manipulation, integer-sequence, nested-function

I tried do define two *OIES Sequences* like that:

```
A035327[n_]:=ResourceFunction["OEISSequence"]["A035272"][[n]]
A360142[n_]:=ResourceFunction["OEISSequence"]["A360142"][[n]]
```

So the argument `n` takes the corresponding [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) of the sequence [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)

But then

```
A035327[A360142[1]]
```

returns

```
List
```

If not "nested" it works fine.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: It looks like `A035327[0]` isn't defined!

Comment: Darn! Iam sorry, too stupid!! Shall I delete the question?

Comment: Let the community decide. It will be very likely closed. But as for deleted, I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Explanation

It's not about nesting, it's about the argument. You are doing `{a,b,c}[[0]]`.

```
ResourceFunction["OEISSequence"]["A360142"]
(* {0,1,2,2,4,5,8,9,10,17,18,18,20,35,36,37,40,69,73,74,81,138,145,146,146,148,163,276,291,292,293,296,325,553,582,585,586,593,650,1105,1162,1169,1170,1172,1187,1300,2211,2324,2339,2340,2341,2344,2373,2601} *)

A360142[1]
(* 0 *)
```

So

```
A035327[A360142[1]]
```

is the same as

```
A035327[0]
```

[`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) zero of any expression is its [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html)

[image]

Therefore,

```
A035327[0]
(* List *)
```

As well as

```
{0,1,2,2,4,5}[[0]]
(* List *)
```

## Solution

```
ClearAll[A035327,A360142,A035272];
A035272[n_Integer?17>=n>=1] := ResourceFunction["OEISSequence"]["A035272"][[n]]
A360142[n_Integer?54>=n>=1] := ResourceFunction["OEISSequence"]["A360142"][[n]]
```

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot, how embarassing!!

Comment: @RaphaelJ.F.Berger not embarrassing we all make mistakes, in my case, many times a day. In the future try debugging with `Echo` and `Trace`.